# SQLITE sum of alias column

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am sure this question has been asked several times, but it seems I can't fix it myself. I want to get the sum of Profit as sumProfit as well the sum of ST as sumST, how exactly should I write the query?

```
SELECT C.Match_ID, M.Match_Date, T1.TeamName as HomeTeam,
T2.TeamName as AwayTeam, L.League_MyName, S.Season_Year, M.algo,
Round((tp.Home*100),3) as TOP,
case when Round((tp.Home*100),3)=0 then 0 
else Round(1/(tp.Home),3) end as TOd,                                                        
LW.Home as LW,
case when Pr.Home=0 then 0.0 else Round((tp2.Home*100),3) end as TV,
Pr.Home as BOd,
case when Pr.Home=0 then 0.0 else Round((1/Pr.Home)*100,3) end as BOP,
case when Pr.Home=0 then 0.0 when Pr.Home<2 then 100.0 else Round(100.0/(Pr.Home-1),2) end as ST,
case when Pr.Home =0 then 0.0 when LW.Home = 'W' then Round((case when Pr.Home<2 then 100.0 else Round(100.0/(Pr.Home-1),2) end) * (Pr.Home-1),2)  
when LW.Home = 'DNB' then 0.0 else -(case when Pr.Home<2 then 100.0 else Round(100.0/(Pr.Home-1),2) end) end as Profit
FROM Matches as M
inner join (select Home, Match_ID from Computations where Computation_Type_ID = 1) as tp on tp.Match_ID = C.Match_ID
inner join (select Home, Match_ID from Computations where Computation_Type_ID = 2) as tp2 on tp2.Match_ID = C.Match_ID
inner join Computations as C on C.Match_ID = M.Match_ID
inner join Leagues as L on L.Real_League_ID = M.Real_League_ID
inner join Season as S on S.Season_ID = M.Season_ID
inner join Teams as T1 on T1.Team_ID = M.Home_TeamID
inner join Teams as T2 on T2.Team_ID = M.Away_TeamID
inner join LostWon as LW on LW.Match_ID=C.Match_ID
inner join Prices as Pr on Pr.Match_ID=C.Match_ID
where M.Real_League_ID=44
group by C.Match_ID
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: I tried SUM(case when Pr.Home=0 then 0.0 when Pr.Home<2 then 100.0 else Round(100.0/(Pr.Home-1),2) end) as sumST

Answer (score 0):

Just make this one as inner query and remove group at very bottom of your inner query

```
SELECT Match_ID, SUM(Profit) as SUMPROFIT, SUM(ST) SUMST FROM (
SELECT C.Match_ID, M.Match_Date, T1.TeamName as HomeTeam,
    T2.TeamName as AwayTeam, L.League_MyName, S.Season_Year, M.algo,
    Round((tp.Home*100),3) as TOP,
    case when Round((tp.Home*100),3)=0 then 0 
    else Round(1/(tp.Home),3) end as TOd,                                                        
    LW.Home as LW,
    case when Pr.Home=0 then 0.0 else Round((tp2.Home*100),3) end as TV,
    Pr.Home as BOd,
    case when Pr.Home=0 then 0.0 else Round((1/Pr.Home)*100,3) end as BOP,
    case when Pr.Home=0 then 0.0 when Pr.Home<2 then 100.0 else Round(100.0/(Pr.Home-1),2) end as ST,
    case when Pr.Home =0 then 0.0 when LW.Home = 'W' then Round((case when Pr.Home<2 then 100.0 else Round(100.0/(Pr.Home-1),2) end) * (Pr.Home-1),2)  
    when LW.Home = 'DNB' then 0.0 else -(case when Pr.Home<2 then 100.0 else Round(100.0/(Pr.Home-1),2) end) end as Profit
    FROM Matches as M
    inner join (select Home, Match_ID from Computations where Computation_Type_ID = 1) as tp on tp.Match_ID = C.Match_ID
    inner join (select Home, Match_ID from Computations where Computation_Type_ID = 2) as tp2 on tp2.Match_ID = C.Match_ID
    inner join Computations as C on C.Match_ID = M.Match_ID
    inner join Leagues as L on L.Real_League_ID = M.Real_League_ID
    inner join Season as S on S.Season_ID = M.Season_ID
    inner join Teams as T1 on T1.Team_ID = M.Home_TeamID
    inner join Teams as T2 on T2.Team_ID = M.Away_TeamID
    inner join LostWon as LW on LW.Match_ID=C.Match_ID
    inner join Prices as Pr on Pr.Match_ID=C.Match_ID
    where M.Real_League_ID=44)
GROUP BY Match_ID
```

If you want to see more columns you can add aliases in outer query but dont forget to add them also group by.

Comment: it's not returning the sum of ALL the Profit column

Comment: You should check here then

    `case when Pr.Home =0 then 0.0 when LW.Home = 'W' then Round((case 
    when 
    Pr.Home<2 then 100.0 else Round(100.0/(Pr.Home-1),2) end) * (Pr.Home-1),2)  
    when LW.Home = 'DNB' then 0.0 else -(case when Pr.Home<2 then 100.0 else 
    Round(100.0/(Pr.Home-1),2) end)`

Make sure you have all desired profit solution in your query.

Comment: I tried to manually sum the results generated by my query, everything is fine

Comment: `where M.Real_League_ID=44` may cause?

Comment: the SUMPROFIT and SUMST are double of what they should be, perhaps this is because I removed group by C.Match_ID ??

Comment: No its not related with that, there is smth in your query creating doubles. Check joins and continue from 1 record will make everything simpler